# accessing an array in the method by sending an element C#

Tags: c#, arrays

i wanted to make my normal array to a circular array by declaring a method
for example this can be my char array:

```
char[] c = Console.ReadLine().ToCharArray();
```

i wanted to declare e method that i can use like this:

```
char c1=c[3].nextItem();
```

and if my array length was bigger than 4 it returns c[4]
else
it returns c[0]
is there any way to declare a method like nextItem() without sending whole array to the method?

Comment: As it stands, your method takes a `char` as an argument (assuming it's an extension method), so in fact it has no idea there is an array. So no, at some point, the whole array must be passed to a helper method. Maybe the question is, why is passing the whole thing a problem at all?

Comment: If you did create a method - the whole array would not be sent to the method, just a reference to the array - so it wouldn't be any different passing a single element array to passing a 1000000 element array.

Comment: Is an extension method acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use, `char c1=c[3].nextItem();`, the method starts from the `char`, not from the array and you don't have the knowledge about the array.

A proposition to create a custom method for the array `char` :

```
public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static char nextItem(this char[] chars, int index)
        {
            //index start from 0
            // my array length was bigger than 4 it returns c[4]
            if(chars.length() > index+1) 
              return chars[index+1];
            else
              //it returns c[0]
              return chars.Length() > 0 ? chars[0] : '';
        }
    }
```

And the calling:

```
char[] c = Console.ReadLine().ToCharArray();
var singleChar = c.nextItem(3);
```

Comment: And this ends up receiving the full array.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
char c1 = (index < c.Length - 1) ? c[index].nextItem() : c[0];
```

If you want a method, you could just return the index:

```
char c1 = c[CheckIndex(index, c.Length())];    

public static int CheckIndex(int index, int length)
{
    return index < length - 1 ? index : 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks but i want a method to do that for me and i cant access the array if i send an element of that array to the method

Comment: I think what OP wants is for the nextItem() method to increment index & wrap if longer than the length of the array.

Comment: @Fake Updated it with a method.  You'd have to pass the array length too.  Hope it helps!